# What is the correct order for several adverbs of time in a sentence?

Tags: adverbs, time-words

In which order should I put the adverbs of time? Should I put the more specific adverb before the less specific one or the other way around?
What's the rule for ordering adverbs of time in a sentence?

> I'm meeting her tomorrow in the evening. / I'm meeting her in the
>   evening tomorrow?
>
> I'm coming to see them tomorrow at 5. / I'm coming to see them at 5
>   tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these time frame usages, you have some flexibility as to word order.

> I'm meeting her tomorrow, in the evening.
>
> I'm meeting her in the evening tomorrow.
>
> I'm meeting her tomorrow evening.

^ All of these are correct and exactly identical in meaning.  The last one is probably more common in use.

> I'm coming to see them tomorrow at 5.
>
> I'm coming to see them at 5 tomorrow.

Both of these are also fine, and meaning-identical.

So, it's up to you!

Answer (score 2):

"Tomorrow evening" is idiomatic. "Evening tomorrow" is *not*.

You could say "I'm meeting her in the evening, tomorrow", but it does rather sound like you're clarifying what you mean rather than qualifying.

When it comes to the time - either way around is fine and equally as common. "Tomorrow at 5" or "at 5 tomorrow" work just as well.

Comment: Right, evening tomorrow is not idiomatic. But still, one might say: I'm meeting her in the evening, tomorrow. [as opposed to in the morning or afternoon].

Comment: It's not idiomatic but it's grammatical and fully intelligible.  This construction is heard all the time in speech without a comma pause.  In general prepositions of time are indifferent to order inter se in English.  There's no reason to avoid use.